# Responsive extension - Hide all columns but the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using most recent version of jQuery DataTables with Responsive extension.

Everything works fine for tablets or desktops, but if the screen falls below say `600px`. I have 4 columns when the responsive kicks in it hide only 1 columns in some tablets is fine but some mobiles only hide 2 columns leaving me with 2 columns on display.

I want to hide the last 3 columns and leave only the first column only if possible when the screen or mobile falls below `600px` width.

I was reading the DataTables documentation but I couldn't find anything for hiding all when screen falls below X width.

```
$('#teamTable').DataTable({
    iDisplayLength: 50,
    columns: [
        {width: '220px' },
        null,
        null
    ],
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column'
        }
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0,0 ] }
    ],

    oLanguage: {
        oPaginate: {
            sNext: "Next Play",
            sPrevious: "Prv. Play"
        },
        sInfo: "_TOTAL_ plays, showing (_START_ of _END_)",
        sSearchPlaceholder: "Linker...",
        sSearch: ''
    }
});
```

I know I'm using option names from previous version of DataTables but they still work.

So how can I hide all but one column when screen falls below X, I can do that using CSS but the idea is to be able to use the jQuery DataTable.

Answer (score 2):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`responsive.breakpoints`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.breakpoints) along with [`columns.className`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) to control visibility of some columns for certain browser widths. See [Class logic](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes) page for more information.

To collapse all columns except the first in a 4-column table when browser width is 600px or more, use the code below. I omitted some code for the sake of simplicity:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
        breakpoints: [
            { name: 'screen-xs',  width: 600 }
        ]
    },

    columnDefs: [
        { className: 'screen-xs': targets: [1,2,3] }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class control to certain columns in order to specify which columns should be displayed on screens with ceratin resolution. Either by the `class` attribute for the table header (https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/classes.html) or by using the `columns.className` option (https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/init-classes.html)

In your case that could probably look like the following:

```
$('#teamTable').DataTable({
    iDisplayLength: 50,
    columns: [
        {width: '220px', className: 'all'},
        null,
        null
    ],
    // here comes the rest ...
});
```